# bash with multiple long options

Tags: bash

I've got a bash script that I don't want reading the bashrc or bash profile. so I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash --norc --noprofile
echo ran
```

it gives me this error:

```
> ./tst.sh 
/bin/bash: --norc --noprofile: invalid option
Usage:  /bin/bash [GNU long option] [option] ... 
GNU long options:
    --debug
    --debugger
    --dump-po-strings
    --dump-strings
    --help
    --init-file
    --login
    --noediting
    --noprofile
    --norc
    --posix
    --protected
    --rcfile
    --rpm-requires
    --restricted
    --verbose
    --version
    --wordexp
```

it appears that I may only specify one long option, but I can't find that documented. the --noprofile is probably over kill, but I'm still curious why I can't specify multiple long options

Comment: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#splitting

Comment: The shebang is documented in `execve(2)`. The Ubuntu execve man page is here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/execve.2.html

Comment: I didn't really see anything in either of these that explained why the 2nd arg was an issue. I see things about a line being too long, but that doesn't appear to be the issue in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that you can specify at most ***one*** word of options on the shebang line (it doesn't have anything to do with long or short options).

More precisely, the `execve` function of your OS passes everything that follows `#!/bin/bash` as ***a single*** argument to bash. This results in the same as the execution of

```
bash "--norc --noprofile"
```

which produces your error.

As pointed out by the links in the comments ([in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#splitting](http://in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#splitting) and [manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/execve.2.html](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/execve.2.html)) this behaviour is OS-specific, and the variations include:

- All words as a single argument (your case)
- Each word as a separate argument (what you were expecting)
- Only first word as a single argument
- No arguments at all

**Conclusion:** on your OS you can't specify multiple words of arguments for bash on the shebang line, and even if you could, you probably shouldn't, because the script would fail on operating systems that don't support multiple shebang arguments.